# How to reuse a REST methods in different resources?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Hi,

I am building a REST-api using Jersey and Java. I wonder if it is possible to reuse a method in many resources.

As an example If I have this code:

```java
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{uid}/comments")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return commentService.getOnEntity("User", uid);
    }   
}
```

and this:

```java
@Path("/items")
public class ItemResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{uid}/comments")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return commentService.getOnEntity("Item", uid);
    }   
}
```

Is it possible to reuse the code for specifying the method "/{uid}/comments/" so I do not need to write it in every resource that is going to need it?

I guess I could extend a CommentResource with the method, but the I can only add one set of methods. If I use Interface I could specify more than one set of methods but would have to rewrite the code inside the methods in every resource.

**Edit**
After a tips from @thomas.mc.work I rewrote my code using a sub resource. It is better than the first solution since I get all methods from my sub resource and it only takes 4 lines of code per resource. This is how it looks like:

```java
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    @Path("/{uid}/comments")
    public CommentSubResource getCommentSubResource(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
        return new CommentSubResource("User", uid);
    }   
}
```

and this:

```java
@Path("/items")
public class ItemResource {

    @Path("/{uid}/comments")
    public CommentSubResource getCommentSubResource(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
        return new CommentSubResource("Item", uid);
    }   
}
```

and this:

```java
public class CommentSubResource {

    private String entity;
    private String entityUid;

    public CommentSubResource(String entity, String entityUid) {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.entityUid = entityUid;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return commentService.getOnEntity(entity, entityUid);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Comment> deleteComment(@PathParam("uid") String uid) {
        return commentService.delete(uid);
    }
}
```

This is much better. I have an idea to use java 8 and default implementation interfaces to be able to just implmenet an interface to get the functionality, but I am not sure if I am able to determine which resource the default implemented method is called from.

**Edit**
After some laboration I think subresources is the way to go, even if it´s not (according to me) the perfect solution.

Comment: You can probably do it with some wildcard trickery. Why on earth are you passing an entity name as a `String` to your `CommentService`? I'd be more worried about that, than what your question is about.

Comment: You could create a separate resource for handling comments only? All requests to comments can be handled by that resource by using a wildcard in the path. e.g., /*/{uid}/comments.

Comment: @Kayaman: I am not sending a String as the entity value, it was just to simplify my example. @Priyesh: That would be a pretty good solution but I would need to do it with `/{entity}/{uid}/comments` and would have to check if the specified entity is suppose to have the comment functionality, or am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar feature called ["Subresource Locators"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gknav.html#gkrhr). You can decide in runtime which Resource is selected to process the request that is matching your JAX-RS method.

Comment: I do not get how I would be able to use this in my example? If I understand how to use it I would have to add a method `getComment()` in two subresources `ItemSubResource` and `UserSubResource` and then write the method twice anyway.

Comment: I found out how I can use subresources to provide all methods of a subresource to a parent resource with very little code. But I still have to write the method for providing the sub resource to the parent resource. I will try to combine it with using java 8 and default implementation interface. Could I maybe create my own custom annotation to solve this?